# Distinguishing "Eskimo"/"Inuit" languages by the passive agent morpheme

Tags: linguistic-typology, cases, morphological-typology, language-identification, passive

In *The Origin of Agent Markers* by Enrique L. Palancar an attempt has been made to list morphemes used both 1.) as **a case morpheme belonging to a noun** and 2.) as **a morpheme on such nouns that express the agent in a passive (main) sentence**<sup>1</sup> (in the book this is referred to as **case syncretism**).

For each of those morphemes, there is given a) the "language name" (that was probably assigned in a source grammar), b) the written form and c) one or more specific semantic categories (e.g.: "Ablative", "Perlative", "Instrumental" etc.).<sup>2</sup>

Unfortunately, there are several entries that list unclear language names.

### Please help distinguish these 3 "Eskimo" languoids. I would like to be able to assign a specific iso code (or glottocode) to each:

1. "Greenlandic" - Suffix *-mik* (Semantics: Instrumental, as in "with/using something")
2. "Labrador XIX" - Suffix *-nun* (Allative (as in "to some place"), Dative (as in "for someone"))
3. "Inuktitut" - Suffix *-mut* (Instrumental, Dative, Cause),
   Suffix *-mit* (Ablative, as in "away from somewhere")

There is a language tree with all the existing languages and corresponding codes at [glottolog.org](http://glottolog.org/resource/languoid/id/eski1265).

---

(The following are the agent morphemes that belong to the 3 most closely related languages that are listed as well. I am quite confident that I am able to assign a specific code to these. You may assume that the languages above are distinct from those below.

5. "West Greenlandic" - Suffix *-mit* (Ablative, Cause), Suffix *-nut* (Allative, Dative)
6. "Alaskan Yupik" - Suffix *-nun* (Allative, Dative)
7. "Siberian Yupik" - Prefix *-ke* (Cause)  )

---

<sup>1</sup> Example agent-marking morpheme in Spanish: "El hombre es matado *POR* el perro." (The man is killed BY the dog.) - *perro* is the kind of "agent" (or "active") NP that would be subject in the sentence "El perro mata al hombre." (The dog kills the man). The morpheme *por* however is also used semantically as a marker e.g. of a location, as in "Pasa por el parque" (He passes *THROUGH* the park). For this particular morpheme, Palancar therefore lists the perlative category (a locative subtype; amongst others).

<sup>2</sup> Just to give you an idea what the original list in Palancar looks like: Here's a short excerpt. It goes on like this for a few pages.
[image: Excerpt from Palancar]

Comment: You should probably just [ask the author directly](http://www.surrey.ac.uk/englishandlanguages/staff_list/complete_staff_list/enrique_palancar/).

Comment: Here's the problem: I'm almost sure that *even the author of that book* only "copied" the language names from the grammars. Sure, I could ask the authors of those grammars...

Comment: If you can get an accurate list of the grammars then they should give you enough info to determine ISO codes. Though I would've expected the book to include the references already...